# How to find the controller mapped to the URL in spring annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-annotations

When am asked to fix an issue, by understanding the code-flow, i find the URL which is been hit and then i go to the controller which is mapped to that particular URL

I find the process `very tedious` as we have some 50 controller classes and more methods annotated with urls inside it

Right now, i use search-option in eclipse IDE and finding the URL pattern annotated to a method

**Is there any easy way, where i can get infos like URL mapped to so-and-so method in so-and-so class ???**

Please help me out on this

Comment: I've often thought this is the downside of annotation-based web programming. I like my single XML configuration file, at least for non-trivial groupings of controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using Spring MVC 3.x Checkout the link .

[Endpoint documentation controller for Spring MVC 3.x](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/03/endpoint-documentation-controller-for.html)

Comment: is there any sample on how to use it in the project ?

Comment: for spring 3.0 is there any way to achieve this ?? The class **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** is only since 3.1 . How to achieve the same in 3.0 ??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library can help:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package", 
      new TypeAnnotationsScanner(), new MethodAnnotationsScanner());

Set<Class<?>> controllers = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class);

Set<Method> requestMappings = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(RequestMapping.class);
```